# Change margin programmatically in WPF / C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For this xaml:

```
<WebBrowser Name="test" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

How can I change the web browser control margin on top to be -5 programmatically in C#?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
test.Margin = new Thickness(0, -5, 0, 0);
```

[Alignment, Margins and Padding Overview (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)
[FrameworkElement.Margin (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx)

Comment: this also works with variables for the individual values, as long as they are of the Doubles type.

Answer (score 5):

```
test.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
test.Margin = new Thickness(-5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the control from code behind using the Name property.
In this case, `test.Margin` property can be used to change it dynamically.

Margin is set as thickness, so the solution could be:

```
test.Margin = new Thickness(0,-5,0,0);
```

*Note: Thickness have 4 parameters `viz left, top, right and bottom`. In above solution, we have just changed `top margin`, rest remained unchanged.*