# Change Margin programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I want to change the Margin of a stackpannel depending on the height of the previous stackpannel, for example the height of StackPannel1 is 20 and the Margin of stackpannel2 is 0,height of stackpannel1 + 5,0,0. How can I solve my Problem?

Comment: maybe this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611658/change-margin-programmatically-in-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: already tried this but that's not what I want :(

Comment: Well, then what do you want?

Comment: I want the marign of StackPanel2 to be the height of StackPanel1+5

Comment: Which margin? Top? Left? Bottom? Right? All?

Comment: I ment the top Margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
stackpannel2.Margin = new Thickness(0, StackPannel1.ActualHeight + 5, 0, 0);
```

Make sure to run this code at the appropriate time (i.e. when `ActualHeight` actually has been set or changed by the framework), e.g. in response to the `FrameworkElement.SizeChanged` event.

Comment: It does nothing it stays where it was. I think it is at the right place in the Code because when I just type 0,200,0,0 it does what it should do

Comment: @szoszk When is the code run? Maybe `StackPannel1.ActualHeight` is 0 because it has not been layouted, yet. Please check that with your debugger.

Comment: After initializing the activity, I'll check it

Comment: It doesn't say anything that looks like an error. That's it: [Debuger log](http://pastebin.com/s0hf6wB6)

Comment: @szoszk I'm not talking about an error. When you query the height before it has been assigned by the layouting system, then it simply has a value of 0. What's the value of `int height = StackPannel1.ActualHeight;`?

Comment: Where can I check this?

Comment: @szoszk Sorry, but your questions are getting more and more offtopic... Please find a tutorial on how to use the debugger. Set a breakpoint after the assignment and check the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you must refresh.. the solution `stackpannel2.Margin = new Thickness(0, StackPannel1.ActualHeight + 5, 0, 0);` seems good to me