# Button with codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

There is this XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Table 1" Grid.Column="1" Click="button_Click" CommandParameter="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,31,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118" Height="39"/>
```

I want to do the same thing, in C#, so I've tried something like:

```
Button b1 = new Button();  
b1.Content = "Table 1";
```

This is weird, but it's working:

```
b1.Click += button_Click;
b1.CommandParameter ="1";
```

This, I wanted to write Left, but it's look like he wanted a `int`:

```
b1.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
```

And .... here, i have no idea what to do.

```
b1.Margin = "34,31,0,0";
```

So, if somebody could give me a link about this, or help me translating this xaml, it would be nice.

(Sorry for strange english)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change margin programmatically in WPF / C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611658/change-margin-programmatically-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for the C# code equivalent of that XAML? If so, it would look like this:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Content = "Table 1";
Grid.SetColumn(b, 1);
b.Click += button_Click;
b.CommandParameter = 1;
b.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
b.Margin = new Thickness(34, 31, 0, 0);
Grid.SetRowSpan(b, 2);
b.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
b.Width = 118;
b.Height = 39;
```

Answer (score 0):

to set margin do it `b1.Margin = new Thickness(34, 31, 0, 0);`and to set HorizantalAlign do it `b1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;`