# WPF MVVM bind Margin property of a control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Building a wpf application in MVVM pattern using caliburn.micro.
I need to set the margin property of button dynamically.
There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611658/change-margin-programmatically-in-wpf-c-sharp) and I have had some Idea, but which is not for MVVM.

I have tried this.

XAML

```
<Grid>
<Button Content="Test" Margin="{Binding ButtonMargin}"/>
<Grid/>
```

ViewModel

```
private Thickness _buttonMargin
public Thickness ButtonMargin
{
   get { return _buttonMargin; }
   set
   {
       if (_buttonMargin != value)
       {
           _buttonMargin = value;
           NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ButtonMargin);
       }
   }
}


//constructor
ButtonMargin = new Thickness(20,10,20,10);
```

I cannot see margin applied to Button. It has default margin as 0.

Is this the right way to do? How can I do this?

Comment: What does "no success" mean? Do you observe any errors in the Output window?

Comment: Be more specific. Provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. _Describe_ the problem. Explain _precisely_ what the code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you have tried to fix it and what _specifically_ you are still having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Change the binding mode in xaml as TwoWay

Comment: @VimalCK For what reason? Do you think the Button should *set* the ButtonMargin property in the view model?

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: If you have `Thickness` in your `VM` then I will question your MvvM in this solution. But what you need is a `Style` to handle Margin in your Button and a property on your VM, perhaps `bool`, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in VM? The margin is something purely related to UI and there is no harm putting it in XAML.cs file.

Comment: @Clemens We shouldn't have kept margin property in ViewModel as we have to use a grid with row and colum to keep contained controls to align it. Since he mentioned that margin is not applying to button for what he wrote, my suggestion is to enable the mode.

Comment: @VimalCK What I mean is that *it makes no sense at all* to set Mode=TwoWay on a binding that *never* updates its source property.

Comment: @Clemens How do you know it will never change? We do not see all of the code. The main point is: That kind of property should never occur in any viewmodel. And if so we do not have to care about binding mode at all ;o)

Comment: Whether such a property should be in view model or not is a matter of opinion. There is no technical reason not to have it there. However, setting Mode=TwoWay as a possible solution for a non-working binding is plain nonsense.

Comment: @Rahul could you also post the container of the `Button`? It will behave differently when placed in a `StackPanel` and different in a `Grid`.

Comment: @Xamimax The button is placed inside grid.

Comment: BTW my nickname is xamlmax, I didn't get the notification about your comment. Did you have a look at my answer?

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I'm investigating your answer

Comment: Your code should work provided that the DataContext of the Button is the object where the ButtonMargin is defined and that your have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. But please read  @Peter Duniho's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a `Button`'s `Margin` working within a `Grid`.
Here is a `pure XAML` solution:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO_app.ForRahul"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"//reference to our View Model assembly
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>//setting up the data context of our UserControl
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">//this is the money maker, this style relies on the property of a button but can be easily adapted to Binding with a View Model
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>//sets the margin of a control, you can also put in here "10,10" or "10,10,20,20"
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton Content="Test" />//Button that we modify the Margin
</Grid>
```

And here is an example of how you use it in a Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"//this is where our Control resides
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Control>
        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <local:ForRahul/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
    </Control>
</Grid>
```

If you need any more info let us know.
If you use a `Style` then you can re-use it in your application, if you do it in code then you will have to either make it `static` or you will have to reference an assembly in your projects.
**Assumptions**
I am assuming that you need only one new value for your Margin.
**UPDATE**
For your requirement you need to keep the value somewhere in the XAML I would suggest the `App.xaml` as this is what all your windows will load by default, in there you should have a reference to it like so:

```
<Thickness x:Key="btnMargin" Left="10" Right="10" Top="10" Bottom="10"/>
```

Then when you need to change it based on some logic you use it in the code behind:

```
var newMargin = App.Current.Resources["btnMargin"] as Thickness;//get the thickness
var button = grid.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Content == "Some Text");//find the correct button
button.Margin = newMargin;
```

Comment: How can I change the margin during the run-time?

Comment: Do you mean the value of the Margin? So at the run time you want to change it say from (10,10,10,10) to (20,10,20,10)?

Comment: Yes I need to change, at least first time i need to set it based on some logic. My Idea is set the value inside ViewModel constructor.

Comment: OK so does your Margin depends on the screen size? If so there are other ways of achieving this functionality. View Model should not determine Margin as it is purely Views concern.

Comment: No, Nothing depends on screen size. I just want to set the margin.

Comment: @Rahul Well then do it in the code behind, there is nothing wrong with that. Your View Model must not know anything about the View. I will update my answer with an example of how you can keep it fairly MvvM .